# Rails Conventions: Should you use the routes path helper all the time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A rails application can have a route, say `/shop` and is defined in the routes as:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get "/shop" => "shop#index", as: :shop
end
```

When in the view, what is the Rails convention? Do you use the helper (`shop_path`) or the route (`/shop`)?

```
link_to t(:shop), shop_path

or

link_to t(:shop), "/shop"
```

You know the route will never be changing. Given that information, what are the upsides and downsides of using the helper versus the string?

Comment: Because if you actually do decide to change the route (say you make it `'/shops'`), you only have to change it in one place (routes) rather than every time you linked to `'/shop'`.

Comment: What if you counter and state that route will never change in an apps lifetime. I'm thinking that using the helper also dictates the route is managed by rails instead of another application.

Comment: it is common practice to use the helper rather than the explicit path.  Even if you think your route will never change, it still could. and rather than having the pain of changing everything, you can just change one line in your routes and be done.  Let me pose this question, what do you gain from not using the helper? If there are tangible benefits, then sure, use that.  But if you gain no benefits, why not follow convention?

Comment: @Sean I like your points. It was a question brought up actually by a new rails developer that I had never thought about before: Why use the helper method if you know you're never going to change the route. I immediately thought about convention, however I wondered if there were any other pros besides convention, and DRY routes. As in my previous comment, that came from another engineer. So there's three pros or two if you think your route is never going to change. Do you want to do a summation of your points and I'll hand you the points/winnings?